# Can I specify the type of a DataGrid's items in Xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resharper

In Xaml when creating a data template I can specify the type of the item the DataTemplate will be applied to like so:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Vehicle}">
  <!-- do some stuff with the Vehicle class's properties -->
</DataTemplate>
```

I would like to be able to do the same thing when creating a DataGrid, but it's not an option with the DataType attribute:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" DataType="{x:Type Vehicle}">
     <!-- Create columns that bind to the Vehicle class's properties -->
</DataGrid>
```

A fairly crap workaround is to do it on each column individually:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" DataType="{x:Type Vehicle}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header />
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Vehicle}">
          <!-- bind to a Vehicle class property -->
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header />
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Vehicle}">
          <!-- bind to a Vehicle class property -->
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header />
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Vehicle}">
          <!-- bind to a Vehicle class property -->
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Is there a better way to do this I'm unaware of? If I don't do it, various bits of ReSharper don't cope very well.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `DataTemplate` with the `DataType` at grid-level?

Comment: @JesperGaarsdal I don't see how that would help. You'd still end up with multiple `DataType` properties being set (one for each `DataTemplate`), wouldn't you? Sounds like the OP is trying to avoid that.

Comment: What if in each CellTemplate you just put a content presenter with content={binding} does the global Vehicle template apply to them then?

Comment: Do you actually need a specific `DataTemplate` in each column? If not, you can greatly simplify your XAML by using generic DataGridColumns, such as something like `<DataGridTextColumn Header="VIN" Binding="{Binding VIN}" />`

Comment: So you trying to implement some code just to make Resharper happy? Doesn`t this seem wrong?

Comment: @icebat, I'm trying to implement some code to make it clear where functionality is being used. ReSharper allows us to find that out very simply, but doesn't work in this case. As an added bonus, it would make the Xaml clearer (telling you what it's working on) with added boatloads of duplication (which makes it less clear).

Comment: @Jackson, if you need it anyway, maybe you can create descendant of DataGrid and add DataType property to it? You`ll have to implement some logic and use this custom grid everywehere but it may work.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the data context for design.

This works:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=Vehicle}">
    <!-- Create columns that bind to the Vehicle class's properties -->
    <!-- The pop-up window will not suggest using the Vehicle class's properties :) -->
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"
          d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type Vehicle}, CreateList=True}">
     <!-- Create columns that bind to the Vehicle class's properties -->
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't clear up any of the ReSharper confusion.

Comment: there are no any other way to suspect resharper issues that are you described above. you should add DataType to each column.

Comment: Really there is still no other solution? :o